# Insert elements in next index of NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am adding multiple elements in NSMutableArray but its storing single element at o index. I need to add the elements into next index every time until the end of the loop

```
  for (i=1; i<58; i++) {
        NSString *stringFromInt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
        NSString *strlastName =[[dict objectForKey:stringFromInt]objectAtIndex:7];
        [arrLastName insertObject:strlastName atIndex:i];

      }
```

Comment: So what's your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to add elements to array untill the loop runs, The problem might be with `i`, which is not initialized

```
for (int i=1; i<58; i++) {
    NSString *stringFromInt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
    NSString *strlastName =[[dict objectForKey:stringFromInt] objectAtIndex:7];
    [arrLastName insertObject:strlastName atIndex:i]; // or try [arrLastName addObject:strlastName];
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

This particular code should throw NSRangeException. You can't insert the item at index greater than array count minus one.

Comment: can u give me solution for this

Comment: Here is the solution
    for (int i=1; i<58; i++) {
    NSString *stringFromInt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
    NSString *strlastName =[[dict objectForKey:stringFromInt] objectAtIndex:7];
    [arrLastName insertObject:strlastName atIndex:0]; //Make this as ZERO always insert in the beginning// or try [arrLastName addObject:strlastName];
}    
This should work